# Prevent all users from editing posts except admins using hooks

Tags: capabilities, permissions, post-editor

So I'm attempting to block out all post edits for all users except admins, so I have the following setup:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', [self::class, 'remove_edit_permissions'], 10, 2);

public static function remove_edit_permissions(array $actions = []): array
{
    $user = User::init();
    if (is_null($user)) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!$user->role()->has_capability('manage_options')) {
        if (isset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js'])) {
            unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
        }
        if (isset($actions['edit'])) {
            unset($actions['edit']);
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

This works great, it blocks out the "Quick Edit" and "Edit" buttons in the Admin Post UI such as below:

[image]

**Problem**:

Users are still able to access the edit url and make changes such as this:  https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=10690&action=edit

Is there a way to restrict link editing also?

Is there a much better solutions on editing prevention using some sort of hook or filter?

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can take away users' capabilities with a plugin like User Role Editor, or programmatically. What you'll need to do is collect a list of all your post types that appear in the Editor (Core has Post and Page; plugins and themes may add more) and then remove properties with a plugin.

For example, you can prevent Editors from being able to edit Posts with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Lock down Posts
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_407959_restrict_caps' );

function wpse_407959_restrict_caps() {
    $role = get_role('editor');
    $role->remove_cap( 'create_posts' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'edit_posts' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'edit_published_posts' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'delete_posts' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'delete_published_posts' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'publish_posts' );
}
```

Check your own site to determine all the Roles you need to update, and also check each post type's capabilities list. Some custom post types use default capabilities (i.e. removing `edit_posts` may prevent them from editing your CPT as well) but others map their own custom capabilities you'll also need to remove.